# Why can't one clone a `Space` in Gecode before solving the original one?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gecode

I'm looking for a way to copy `Space` instances in *Gecode* and then analyze the difference between the spaces later.

However it goes already wrong after the first copy. When one copies the code in the book *Modelling and Programming in Gecode*, as shown here below, and simply modifies it such that a copy is made first (`SendMoreMoney* smm = m->copy(true);`), one gets a *Segmentation fault*, regardless whether the `shared` option is `true` or `false`.

```
#include <gecode/int.hh>
#include <gecode/search.hh>

using namespace Gecode;

class SendMoreMoney : public Space {
protected:
  IntVarArray l;
public:
  SendMoreMoney(void) : l(*this, 8, 0, 9) {
    IntVar s(l[0]), e(l[1]), n(l[2]), d(l[3]),
           m(l[4]), o(l[5]), r(l[6]), y(l[7]);
    // no leading zeros
    rel(*this, s, IRT_NQ, 0);
    rel(*this, m, IRT_NQ, 0);
    // all letters distinct
    distinct(*this, l);
    // linear equation
    IntArgs c(4+4+5); IntVarArgs x(4+4+5);
    c[0]=1000; c[1]=100; c[2]=10; c[3]=1;
    x[0]=s;    x[1]=e;   x[2]=n;  x[3]=d;
    c[4]=1000; c[5]=100; c[6]=10; c[7]=1;
    x[4]=m;    x[5]=o;   x[6]=r;  x[7]=e;
    c[8]=-10000; c[9]=-1000; c[10]=-100; c[11]=-10; c[12]=-1;
    x[8]=m;      x[9]=o;     x[10]=n;    x[11]=e;   x[12]=y;
    linear(*this, c, x, IRT_EQ, 0);
    // post branching
    branch(*this, l, INT_VAR_SIZE_MIN(), INT_VAL_MIN());
  }
  // search support
  SendMoreMoney(bool share, SendMoreMoney& s) : Space(share, s) {
    l.update(*this, share, s.l);
  }
  virtual SendMoreMoney* copy(bool share) {
    return new SendMoreMoney(share,*this);
  }
  // print solution
  void print(void) const {
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
  }
};

// main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // create model and search engine
  SendMoreMoney* m = new SendMoreMoney;
  SendMoreMoney* mc = m->copy(true);
  DFS<SendMoreMoney> e(m);
  delete m;
  // search and print all solutions
  while (SendMoreMoney* s = e.next()) {
    s->print(); delete s;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How can one make a real copy?

Comment: You can change the return type of `copy` from `Space` to `SendMoreMoney` and it still counts as an override. This is a special case for derived types.

Comment: @NeilKirk: True, I did that first, but it didn't worked. So I copied the original code back to make sure nothing broke along the way. In the original code, that Liskov substitution wasn't presented. [Modified].

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `status()` on the `Space` first.

Answer (score 1):

I found this exchange in the Gecode mailing list archives: https://www.gecode.org/users-archive/2006-March/000439.html

It would seem that internally, Gecode uses the copy function and constructor for its own internal purposes, so to make a "copy-by-value" copy of a space, you need to use the clone() function defined in the Space interface. However, as noted in @Anonymous answer, you need to call status() before calling clone or it will throw an exception of type `SpaceNotStable`

I augmented my space with the function below to automatically call status, make the clone, and return a pointer of my derived type:

```cpp
struct Example : public Space {
    ...
    Example * cast_clone() {
        status();
        return static_cast<Example *>(this->clone());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, one can create a totally independent space and then use equality constraints
on the variable level to reduce the domains of these variables.

**Example:**

```
void cloneHalfValues(SendMoreMoney* origin) {
    int n = l.size();
    for(int i = 0x00; i < n/2; i++) {
        if(origin->l[i].assigned()) {
            rel(*this, l[i], IRT_EQ, origin->l[i].val());
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why one can't clone a `Space` is however still a mystery.